# Adding more elements to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

**Context:** I'm fetching 'car' data below (see the code that starts with "for") from a GET request and am pushing it to the 'array' array. And for each car.ID that I get, I need to run another GET request in sequence (the GET uses car.ID as a parameter and I have no problems in doing this).

**Problem:** after I fetch the results from the second GET, **how to push the data to the same object of the array (i.e. I want to "complement" the object above that ended on car.BrandID by adding a few more *key: value* pairs to the same "line")?**

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

```
for (let car of carsJustObtained) {
      for (i=0; i<=2; i++){
          
          array.push(
            {
              timestamp: epoch,
              ID    : car.ID,
              BrandID   : car.BrandID
})
//code continues but don't worry
```

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
function gotCars(carsJustObtained) {
 
    for (let car of carsJustObtained) {
      for (i=0; i<=2; i++){
          
          array.push(
            {
              timestamp: epoch,
              ID    : car.ID,
              BrandID   : car.BrandID,
              ModelID   : car.ModelID,
            
            }
          );
//given car.ID the second GET will be triggered because the path depends on this variable!
          
          let path_get_all_prices = `xxx=${car.ID}?securityToken=xxx&vehiclePriceTypeID=xxx`;
        
          let get = https.get(
          {
          hostname: 'xxx.com',
          path: path_get_all_prices
          },
          (getRes) => {
            console.log(`getting prices for car ${car.ID}...`);
            var reply = "";
            getRes.on("data", (chunk) => (reply += chunk));
            const obj = JSON.parse(reply);
            gotPrices(obj.Response);
          }
          );
          
          function gotPrices(pricesJustObtained) {
            for (let price of pricesJustObtained){
              array.push(
                //how to add results to the same array of the 1st GET? There are three 'prices' for each car.ID
              )};
          };
    };
```

Comment: could you please show a little bit more code? This seems too narrow-scoped

Comment: Is `car.push()` what you need?

Comment: Please show in your question the code where you make the second request, and what you have done to add the retrieved information, and how it fails. Right now your code does not show a problem, because there is no requests being made at all.

Comment: Yes I need like a car.push() but ensuring that it is added to the same array from the first GET @BladeMight got it? I don't know how to push to the same array from the first GET - I add it to a second array, "below" the first one and this is a problem.

Comment: Please show the request, some sample data that you get from *both* requests, and the exact outcome you want to have for that example. Make sure to provide enough code (but not more) for us to *reproduce* your problem.

Comment: @DiF If you are looping over array of each GET, and when moving to second GET, last one gets "forgotten", why not try using variable to store "last one": `var last_car; for (...) { do_stuff(); last_car.push(..); ...; last_car=car; }`

Comment: I'm editing the original post to give more context.

Comment: I've edited my post to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the index of your object in your array, then you can add everything you can to this object :

```
array[index].name = 'Hello';
```

Comment: The problem is that the array is inside an object and I don't know how to properly access this array and add elements to it. Thank you for your kind attention!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I recommend you read about `array.map()`

This function lets you iterate your array and in each iteration perform the get request and extend the current element.

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention. Can you tell me more? What I need is to add the new data to the SAME array as additional "columns" (i.e. rather than inserting as a new "row").

Answer (score 0):

#### The key is to recognise that you are not pushing, the second time

What you are doing is reading each element of the array, and adding some information to *that element*.

```
for (let car of carsJustObtained) {
  
   const newInfo=getFurtherInformationAboutCar(car) // this is your second getting
   
   car.newInfo1 = newInfo.param1;
   car.newInfo2 = newInfo.param2;
   car.newInfo3 = newInfo.param3;
}
```

#### To answer your specific question about "merging" information

If you have one set of properties already defined for the car, and you want to merge in multiple new properties, a simple way to do it is as follows:

```
car = { ...car, ...objectContainingNewProperties};
```

If your original `car` was `{a:2, b:3, c:4}` and objectContainingNewProperties was `{c: 10, d:20, e:30}`, the result would be:

```
{ a:2,
  b:3,
  c:10,
  d:20,
  e:30 }
```

Any same-named properties in the second object will overwrite those in the original object.

Comment: This is brilliant. Let me try and get back to you. Thank you so much for your kind attention.

Comment: No success. I'm posting the full code now to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

Your second request is of course asynchronous, so by the time you get its response, you have already populated your array with all information from the first request.

I would suggest to use a promise-enabled alternative to `http.get`, as promises are a native feature in JavaScript that makes working with asynchronous events less messy. I will show here how it can work with [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

As `fetch` is natively supported in browser agents, you can run the snippet below to see the result. As a demo I have used https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ as a server resource: it returns JSON for several sample datasets, including todos and users. A todo has some properties (like a title) and has a user id. A user has an email and a username. So we could make the todos-request the first request, and the users-request the second one (based on the user id received in the first). So the principle is the same as with your cars and prices.

This relies heavily on promises:

```js
// For demo, we use these two URls:
// They both need a number following it
let url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
let url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";

let promises = [];
// Let's say we build an array with 5 objects:
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    promises.push(
        // Make the request
        fetch(url1 + i*30)
            // Parse the response as JSON
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            // Process this data
            .then(data => {
                // Create our own object from this data
                let obj = {
                    user: data.userId,
                    todo: data.title
                };
                // Make second request, to get user's email, joining it with obj
                return Promise.all([obj, fetch(url2 + obj.user)])
            })
            .then(([obj, resp2]) => Promise.all([obj, resp2.json()]))
            // Merge the new data with the old
            .then(([obj, data2]) => Object.assign(obj, {
                email: data2.email,
                logon: data2.username
            }))
    );
}
// Wait for all requests to finish...
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log(results); // The result!
});
```

### With async/await

The above can be made even more readable, if you use the `async`/`await` syntax:

```js
let url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
let url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";

async function getOne(i) {
    let resp = await fetch(url1 + i*30);
    let data = await resp.json();
    // Create object from first request
    let obj = {
        user: data.userId,
        todo: data.title
    };
    // Make second request, joining it with obj
    let resp2 = await fetch(url2 + obj.user);
    let data2 = await resp2.json();
    return Object.assign(obj, {
        email: data2.email,
        logon: data2.username
    });
}

let promises = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    promises.push(getOne(i));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```